# Should I be setting up my Django app on my server via SSH or locally?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, django

Ok noob question: I have a little micro AWS EC2 instance running, and I'm going through [this](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/Install_Django_and_Build_Your_First_App) Django tutorial. SSH'ing into my EC2 means that all the work I'm doing, like editing the config files, making Django apps/projects, etc. is very slow, with lag (my internet connection is not fast).

Could/should I be doing most of the work locally, then just uploading the files to the correct locations when I'm done, and then do all the apache configurations through the slow SSH only?

Answer (score 1):

Working on the file locally:

- Pros: You edit the file locally with zero lag.
- Cons: You need to upload the file in order to test.

Working on the file remotely:

- Pros: The file is immediately available for your app.
- Cons: You have to deal with lag while editing.

Not quite sure what else there is--if the lag is bothering you, edit it locally and upload it (or consider using something like [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html)).

Comment: +1.  Work locally, push back for testing.